# Mapbox Flutter: 'A valid access token parameter is required' error

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

I have been successfully using Mapbox API with my Flutter application. However, after a significant number of requests, I started encountering the following error:

```
E/Mbgl (14179): {ample.untitled1}[Setup]: loading style failed: A valid access token parameter is required when using a Mapbox service.
E/Mbgl (14179): Please see https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/ to learn how to create one.
E/Mbgl (14179): More information in this guide https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#access-tokens.Currently provided token is: null
```

I have ensured that I properly configured Mapbox according to the documentation, and it was working without any issues initially

It seems like the access token is now null or invalid, causing the map styles to fail loading. Initially, the API was working without any issues.

I'm using Mapbox with Flutter and have followed the instructions provided in the Mapbox documentation to set up the access token. I've ensured that the token is being passed correctly to the Mapbox API calls. However, I'm still encountering this issue.

Could someone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've verified the validity and correctness of my Mapbox access token and ensured its proper integration within my Flutter application's code. Despite these checks, the error persists. Initially, I expected the Mapbox services to function seamlessly as they did before, given the correct configuration of the access token